# if else statement in es6/template-literals with array

Tags: jquery, template-literals

I had a es6 statement (backtick) and i wish to do if else checking for condition. I tried to do the if else outside the loop but it's not working.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   

   RECORDS_type3.forEach((record, index) => {
        $('#predictionHistory table tbody').append(`<tr class="br-record-row type3">
                 <td><div>${record.predictionTeamOne} <br>VS<br>  ${record.predictionTeamTwo}</div></td>
                  <td>${record.date}</td>
                 <td><div class="bet-brand">${record.betTeam}</div> <span>${record.productCat}</span><div class="betStatus-${record.betStatusType}">${record.betResult}</div></td>
              /* i want do if else statement to show different div
                 if((record.matchCountDown)>0){
                    <td class="wh-countdown">${record.matchCountDown}</td>

                }
                else{
                    <td class="wh-${record.inOut}">${record.amount}</td>

                }*/ this part
            

                 </tr>`);
    });
    
});
```

And i am using array

```
var RECORDS_type3 = [{
        predictionTeamOne: 'England',
        predictionTeamTwo: 'Austria',
        date: '13 June 2021 9:00PM',
       countdown:"03:00:00"
       ..etc
       
    },
```

so i wanna check  when countdown="00:00:00" then i will perform the if else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate some chunks of HTML string made using templating literals.

```
RECORDS_type3.forEach((record, index) => {

  let htmlToAppend = `<tr class="br-record-row type3">
    <td><div>${record.predictionTeamOne} <br>VS<br>  ${record.predictionTeamTwo}</div></td>
    <td>${record.date}</td>
    <td><div class="bet-brand">${record.betTeam}</div> <span>${record.productCat}</span><div class="betStatus-${record.betStatusType}">${record.betResult}</div></td>`;
    
    /* Your condition here */
    if((record.matchCountDown)>0){
      htmlToAppend += `<td class="wh-countdown">${record.matchCountDown}</td>`;
    }
    else{
      htmlToAppend += `<td class="wh-${record.inOut}">${record.amount}</td>`
    }

    htmlToAppend += `</tr>`;

  $('#predictionHistory table tbody').append(htmlToAppend);
});
```

Comment: can i add "alert " before 
                htmlToAppend += `<td class="wh-countdown">${record.matchCountDown}</td>`;
?

Comment: Sure... But that alert will stop the loop execution until you close the alert... It may be better to use `console.log()`

Comment: hi @Louys Patrice Bessette, THanks for your help... Its working, but i found that my looping will loop twice (my original code). Do u have any idea why?

Comment: no... All I see is one correct `foreach()` loop.

Comment: Maybe there is duplicate entries in `RECORDS_type3`? Add `console.log(index)` just before the `if` statement...

Comment: i added log before if statement and yes, console.log display output for twice. But in my document.ready.function, only have this function

Comment: Hi, i fixed it. I accidentally call the js script in another html. So looping happen. Thanks for your help